# Trying to get PHP responce on ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here I am trying to update the MSQL table using jQuery, both PHP code and jQuery script is written on the same page, the code working fine to update my tables but the response msg is not getting by the AJAX so it always shows me the default message "Some problem occurred, please try again.".

**HTML**

```
<!-- HTML code to display msg -->
<p class="statusMsg_post"></p>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn_publish').click( function() {           
            var obj_post_postID="<?php echo $post_id; ?>";
            var publish_post="publish";

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                // url:'post_view.php',
                data:{
                    "post_status_update": publish_post,
                    "obj_post_status": obj_post_postID,
                },
                success:function(res) {
                    if (res=='ok') {                       
                        $('.statusMsg_post').html('<span style="color:green;">Post has been '+publish_post+' sucessfully</span>');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.statusMsg_post').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                    }
                }
            });         
        });         
    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
// my PHP code to update my table

<?php
    // require_once('../../inc/db-connect.php');

    if (isset($_POST['post_status_update'])) {
        $temp_publish_post = $_POST['post_status_update'];

        echo $bj_post_postID = $_POST['obj_post_status'];

        $obj_post_status_query = "UPDATE `objection_report` SET `obj_status` = '$temp_publish_post' WHERE `objection_report`.`obj_post_id` = $bj_post_postID;";

        $obj_post_status_query .= "UPDATE `post` SET `status` = '$temp_publish_post' WHERE `post`.`post_id` = $bj_post_postID ;";

        if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $obj_post_status_query)) {
            echo "ok";      
            die;
        }
    }
?>
```

all the above codes are on the same page

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: To start debugging, check the value of res being passed to the success function: `window.console.log(res);` <-- add this above the `if (res == 'ok')` line.

Comment: have you tried outputting res to the console to see what the value is? console.log(res); sorry jef, added at the same time.

Comment: thanx for the suggestion.

Comment: I am new with the jquery and ajax

Comment: Would it not be a good idea to pass back something when the query failes to tell that javascript something?

Comment: "both PHP code and jquery script is written on the same page"  That's probably your problem right there.

Comment: This script will return `<p class="statusMsg_post"></p>` before your status, and anything else that is HTML and lives above that line

Comment: yes @PatrickQ that's the problem, if i separate them into different files then its working fine

Comment: but @RiggsFolly the code working fine if I separate them into different files

Comment: Right, and there's a reason why.  And it's why you should get into the habit of separating your business logic from your display logic.  They're two completely different aspects of your website/application, and really have no business being in the same file.

Comment: Yes possibly. But remember, EVERYTHING this script returns to the browser, INCLUdING all the HTML will get sent back to the AJAX Call. And most of the HTML looks like it happens BEFORE your attempt to return `OK`

Comment: the problem occurs only when I put codes into a single file

Comment: As @PatrickQ suggests in a round about way, Make your PHP code that run in reply to an AJAX Call work like an API and place it in a seperate script

Comment: Please listen to what you're being told. When you put everything in one file, and don't explicitly control what gets output with PHP conditionals, then all possible output, _including the HTML, Javascript, CSS, etc_ will be returned in your ajax response.  You should _not_ make an ajax request to a page that outputs HTML if you are expecting a text or JSON response.

Comment: Can you please check after removing echo from $bj_post_postID=$_POST['obj_post_status']; statement. check it and let me know.

Comment: Use the browsers DEBUGGER to look at what gets placed into your js `res` variable

Comment: okay guys thanx for the suggestion, thanx @PatrickQ and guys

Comment: it doesn't work @Let'sEnkindle

Answer (score 0):

The script is returning the HTML and JS on the ajax call. If you put checks around the HTML it will not:

```
<?php if ( ! isset( $_POST['post_status_update'] ) ): ?>
    <p class="statusMsg_post"></p>

    <script>
        $( document ).ready( function () {
            $( '#btn_publish' ).click( function () {

                var obj_post_postID = "<?php echo $post_id; ?>";
                var publish_post = "publish";

                $.ajax( {
                    type: 'POST',
//          url:'post_view.php',
                    data: {
                        "post_status_update": publish_post,
                        "obj_post_status": obj_post_postID,
                    },
                    success: function ( res ) {
                        if ( res === 'ok' ) {

                            $( '.statusMsg_post' ).html( '<span style="color:green;">Post has been ' + publish_post + ' sucessfully</span>' );
                        } else {
                            $( '.statusMsg_post' ).html( '<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>' );
                        }
                    }
                } );
            } );
        } );
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```